# How to make HTML (divs) + jQuery code into just jQuery that generates the HTML

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML on a page which I use jQuery to modify/add data to from an array. I'd like to use jQuery to generate the HTML/Divs & img src if possible to stop having to manually edit each page with the amount of required divs in HTML. I don't have access to a database for this.

The HTML markup looks like this, which I have to copy and paste for the amount of items in the array:

```
<!-- START ITEM --><div class="itemWrapper"><a href="" class="itemLink">
<!-- IMG  --><img src="" class="itemImage"></a>
<!-- TITLE --><div class="itemTitle">T</div>
<!-- INFO --><div class="itemDesc"></div></div>
<!-- END ITEM -->
```

And the jQuery is on document.ready:

```
var infoArray = [
      'ABC12_square','Square','Square Description Here',
      'ABC13_polygon','Polygon','Polygon Description Here',
      'ABC14_triangle','Triangle','Triangle Description Here',
    ];
      $BoP = 'tag+info+here';
    
      i0 = 0;
      i1 = 1;
      i2 = 2;
      
    $('.itemImage').each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr("src", infoArray[i0]);
      i0 = i0+3;
      var prR = $(this).attr("src");
      var subprR = jQuery.trim(prR).substring(0, 5);
      $(this).attr("src", "/images/info/"+prR+"_M.jpg");
      $(this).parent().attr("href", "/iteminfopopup.htm?codes="+prR+"&BoP="+$BoP).attr('rel', 'mygroup').addClass('BoP8 fancybox.iframe');
      $(this).parent().append('<img src="/images/info/'+subprR+'_H.jpg" class="itemHover" border="0" width="250" height="354">');
    });
       
    $(".itemTitle").each(function(index) {
      $(this).text(infoArray[i1]);
      i1 = i1+3;
    });
    
    $(".itemDesc").each(function(index) {
      $(this).text(infoArray[i2]);
      i2 = i2+3;
    });
    // Setup Fancybox
  $(".BoP8").fancybox({
      closeBtn    : true,
      maxWidth  : 467,
      maxHeight  : 609,
      fitToView  : false,
      padding   : '5',
      openEffect  : 'none',
      loop: false,
      closeEffect  : 'none',
      nextEffect : 'none',
      prevEffect : 'none'
  });
    // Create image hover animation
  $(".itemImage").hover(
     function() {$(this).animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");},
     function() {$(this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");}
   );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZuPnp/

I've looked at append but it keeps going hideously wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Clone function inside jQuery. Thats probably what you are looking for. More information can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

here's an example of how you could use this:

```
<div id="holder">
<div class="itemWrapper"><a href="" class="itemLink">
<img src="" class="itemImage"></a>
<div class="itemTitle">T</div>
<div class="itemDesc"></div></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var infoArray = [
          'ABC12_square','Square','Square Description Here',
          'ABC13_polygon','Polygon','Polygon Description Here',
          'ABC14_triangle','Triangle','Triangle Description Here',
        ];

$.each(infoArray, function(index, val){
    //Dont forget to set the new values offcourse.
    $("div.itemWrapper").clone().appendTo("div#holder");
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle example :)

Comment: On the fiddle it creates a lot of cloned divs (50+), when you say set the values - as in the length of the array?

Comment: Yes how to limit the clone number ?

Comment: "if you want to show it for a fixed number you can use for loop"

Comment: I want to repeat it for the length of the array, but I can't quite figure that part out...

Answer (score 0):

Better Use `.prependTo()`   with  `.clone()`

`See example` http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/fSAHp/

If you want to show it for a fixed number you can use for loop